# Want to select variables for training on runtime via placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am looking for a way to select trainable variables for updation in run time based on my epoch id. I understand that I can name a set of variable under variable scope as `tf.variable_scope`.

If I create a placeholder as `train_vars = tf.placeholder(shape = [None], dtype = type(tf.GraphKeys))`, it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Expected DataType for argument 'dtype' not <class 'type'>.
```

What is the correct way to pass this list of trainables via placeholder or is there no way?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use [`tf.stop_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient) and [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) to choose whether the gradients should be back-propagated to a variable, for example like this:

```
v = tf.Variable(...)
v_is_trainable = tf.placeholder((), tf.bool)  # Or tf.placeholder_with_default
v_value = tf.cond(v_is_trainable, lambda: v, lambda: tf.stop_gradient(v))
```

Then just adding `v_is_trainable: True` or `v_is_trainable: False` to the `feed_dict` will make the variable trainable or not for that step.

EDIT: If you want to select the variables by indicating the collection of trainable variables, you could do something like this

```
trainable_vars = tf.placeholder([None], tf.string)
v = tf.Variable(...)
# The variable is trainable if its name is in trainable_vars
v_value = tf.cond(tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(v.name, trainable_vars)),
                  lambda: v, lambda: tf.stop_gradient(v))
```

Then if you have all the variables you want to train in a collection called 'MY_VARS', you could give in the `feed_dict`:

```
trainable_vars: [v.name for v in tf.get_collection('MY_VARS')]
```

Comment: thanks but I just have too many variable to manually manage them. 

Since the graph is defined with the first value of flag, would the graph still change if I push this flag via feed_dict?

Comment: @silent_dev I have added an alternative to select variables by name, see if that helps.